# Successfully passed an array of data to the client via EJS, but it will not let me access the array on the client side when I add an index value

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js, ejs

I am passing data returned from an API to the client via EJS. I am unsuccessfully accessing the returned JSON array on the client side. On the server side I am successfully passing the client the returned data like this:

```
fetch(url)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => res.render('pages/search', {
    venues: JSON.stringify(data.response.venues)
  }))
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
    res.sendStatus(500);
  });
```

The returned JSON I am passing to the client looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": "4bc20e29b492d13a9cdba660",
        "name": "BBQ",
        "contact": {
            "phone": "555-555-555",
            "formattedPhone": "555-555-555",
            "twitter": "bbq",
            "facebook": "162628917087420"
        },
        "location": {
            "address": "XXXX US Hwy 48 North",
            "lat": 22.089288703481692,
            "lng": -80.97257354855537,
            "labeledLatLngs": [
                {
                    "label": "display",
                    "lat": 22.089288703481692,
                    "lng": -80.97257354855537
                }
            ],
            "postalCode": "333333",
            "cc": "US",
            "city": "CITY",
            "state": "FL",
            "country": "United States",
            "formattedAddress": [
                "XXXX US Hwy 48 North",
                "CITY, FL 333333",
                "United States"
            ]
        },
        "categories": [
            {
                "id": "4bf58dd8d48988d1df931735",
                "name": "BBQ Joint",
                "pluralName": "BBQ Joints",
                "shortName": "BBQ",
                "icon": {
                    "prefix": "https://ss3.4sqi.net/img/categories_v2/food/bbqalt_",
                    "suffix": ".png"
                },
                "primary": true
            }
        ],
        "verified": true,
        "stats": {
            "tipCount": 16,
            "usersCount": 946,
            "checkinsCount": 2087
        },
        "url": "https://www.sonnysbbq.com/location/store151",
        "hasMenu": true,
        "menu": {
            "type": "Menu",
            "label": "Menu",
            "anchor": "View Menu",
            "url": "https://www.sonnysbbq.com/menu/",
            "mobileUrl": "https://www.sonnysbbq.com/menu/",
            "externalUrl": "https://www.sonnysbbq.com/menu/"
        },
        "allowMenuUrlEdit": true,
        "beenHere": {
            "lastCheckinExpiredAt": 0
        },
        "specials": {
            "count": 0,
            "items": []
        },
        "storeId": "151",
        "referralId": "v-1520220733",
        "venueChains": [
            {
                "id": "556a31e2a7c8957d73d4874c"
            }
        ],
        "hasPerk": false
    },
    {
        "id": "4bc20e29b492d13a9cdba660",
        "name": "BBQ",
        "contact": {
            "phone": "555-555-555",
            "formattedPhone": "555-555-555",
            "twitter": "bbq",
            "facebook": "162628917087420"
        },
        "location": {
            "address": "XXXX US Hwy 48 North",
            "lat": 22.089288703481692,
            "lng": -80.97257354855537,
            "labeledLatLngs": [
                {
                    "label": "display",
                    "lat": 22.089288703481692,
                    "lng": -80.97257354855537
                }
            ],
            "postalCode": "333333",
            "cc": "US",
            "city": "CITY",
            "state": "FL",
            "country": "United States",
            "formattedAddress": [
                "XXXX US Hwy 48 North",
                "CITY, FL 333333",
                "United States"
            ]
        },
        "categories": [
            {
                "id": "4bf58dd8d48988d1df931735",
                "name": "BBQ Joint",
                "pluralName": "BBQ Joints",
                "shortName": "BBQ",
                "icon": {
                    "prefix": "https://ss3.4sqi.net/img/categories_v2/food/bbqalt_",
                    "suffix": ".png"
                },
                "primary": true
            }
        ],
        "verified": true,
        "stats": {
            "tipCount": 16,
            "usersCount": 946,
            "checkinsCount": 2087
        },
        "url": "https://www.sonnysbbq.com/location/store151",
        "hasMenu": true,
        "menu": {
            "type": "Menu",
            "label": "Menu",
            "anchor": "View Menu",
            "url": "https://www.sonnysbbq.com/menu/",
            "mobileUrl": "https://www.sonnysbbq.com/menu/",
            "externalUrl": "https://www.sonnysbbq.com/menu/"
        },
        "allowMenuUrlEdit": true,
        "beenHere": {
            "lastCheckinExpiredAt": 0
        },
        "specials": {
            "count": 0,
            "items": []
        },
        "storeId": "151",
        "referralId": "v-1520220733",
        "venueChains": [
            {
                "id": "556a31e2a7c8957d73d4874c"
            }
        ],
        "hasPerk": false
    }
]
```

Since this is an array of objects, and there are clearly two main objects in this array, I would expect to be able to access the data on my EJS page like this:

```
<%= venues[0].location.lat =>
```

This does not work at all. I get nothing, but I also get no errors. However, if I do this:

```
<%= venues %>
```

I can render the entire JSON response to the page. But why can I not specifically access the array with an index value? My end goal is to be able to access the Latitude and Longitude coords out of the location object. This is how I expected to accomplish that:

```
<%= venues[0].location.lat %>
<%= venues[0].location.lng %>
```

Note: I will be working in a for loop so I can iterate through the entire returned JSON array, but for this example, I left the loop out and shortened the JSON response to two main objects.

Comment: Maybe try `JSON.parse(venues)[0].location.lat` and `JSON.parse(venues)[0].location.lng` just to test to make sure it's being executed as *actual* JSON code and not just a string or whatnot.

Comment: Hmm should you be using JSON.stringify?

Comment: @thomann061 hey thanks for the suggestion. My server side code does that before it passes the data to the view.

Comment: @TyQ. I will try that. Thank you!

Comment: how is `data.response.venues` related to the "JSON" response?

Comment: That's what I was hinting towards - that you shouldn't be stringifying the json when passing it to ejs :)

Comment: @thomann061 completely read a "shouldn't" when you clearly said "should". Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Change it to:

```
fetch(url)
.then(res => res.json())
.then(data => res.render('pages/search', {
  venues: data.response.venues
}))
.catch(err => {
  console.log(err);
  res.sendStatus(500);
});
```

Templates expect the template vars to be passed as their JS types not stringified JSON.

Comment: I was getting [object Object] when rendering the data without stringifying it from the server first. Any reason why that would be? Would it be right to think that I can just stringify the data on the client side based on what you said about templates?

Comment: Venues should write `[object Object]` since that is what it is. The `<%= venues[0].location.lat %>` should work.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will try that again. Previously I had tried to access [object Object] the way you suggested and it did not work for me. That's why I ended up stringifying the data. I'm sure I was just doing something wrong and dismissed it after stringifying. Again thanks!

Comment: Can I see the code you are using the in the template now?

Comment: this is the template page:

<div id="xyz">
   <%= venues[0].location %>
</div>

that is the entire template page for now. Eventually this data will be used to render a google map with multiple markers, but until I can access the passed data, the template page is just set up so I can make sure I am passing data. 

I just tried to remove the JSON.stringify from the backend, and yes I can pass the data and render all of it with <%= venues %> without stringifying it. However when I want to access it like <%= venues[0].location %> I get nothing.

Comment: More so, when I render the non-stringified JSON to the client with <%= venues %>, the JSON still shows as being stringified when rendered. I get the quotes around the keys in the objects just like when it is stringified.

Answer (score 0):

When you stringify a JSON object, you can no longer access any of the objects keys/values.

E.g. From Mozilla:

> JSON.stringify({ x: 5, y: 6 });
>
> // '{"x":5,"y":6}' <-- Notice the quotes

Now, when you send an `HTTP Request`, `JSON Objects` must be stringified because `HTTP` cannot keep the state of a `JSON Object`.

However, express can, which means the view engine can as well.

The important thing to remember is that the view engine (`ejs` in your case) sends an `HTTP Request` or renders the page **after it is done inserting your `JSON Objects`.**

Answer (score 0):

Almost 48 hours of on and off dealing with this issue, it has finally be resolved. Firstly, thanks to anyone who spent their time to help me, it is very appreciated!

Basically, I needed to use `JSON.stringify()` when passing the returned API data from the server to the client. Once the data was on the client side, I used `JSON.parse()` to wrap the stringified EJS variable:

Server:

```
 fetch(url)
     .then(res => res.json())
     .then(data => res.render('pages/search', {
        userLat: latLng.lat,
        userLng: latLng.lng,
        venues: JSON.stringify(data.response)
     }))
     .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        res.sendStatus(500);
     })
```

Client:

```
<script>
    var test = JSON.parse(<%- JSON.stringify(venues) %>);

    //and a console.log that confirms I can access the data

    console.log(test.venues)

</script>
```

I can now access the objects in the data on the client like I expected to initially. I am using this data with the Google Map API, and I will be rendering the map with this inline `<script>` tag on the page. I am positive there is no way to share data passed with EJS from the server to an external JS file on the client side, so I opted for the rendering just the map with an inline `<script>`.

Here is the thing though, I do not understand why I needed to wrap the EJS variable with `JSON.stringify()`  when the EJS data was sent from the server stringified already. I would really like to know why, and not just go about my business thinking it's black magic haha.

Regardless for now, this fixed my issue!

Comment: There should be no reason you need to stringify the venues data!  This will work: `venues: data.response`. Then on the client - `<% venues[0].location.lat %>`

Comment: @thomann061 I tried that in the beginning and I couldn't get it to output anything like this: <%= venues[0].location.lat %> The subtle difference between what I tried versus what you suggested is that the EJS tag I used will output the value to the template. The scriptlet tag you suggested I have not tried yet. Would that tag make a difference? I don't know if it would. If the data was accessible, then I should be able to use any EJS tag to handle it. For now, stringifying the data before sending it and then parsing it is working for me. I can access the data as expected and all is working.

Comment: I think you are missing something. The `res.json()` is what does the conversion from string to JSON. It still seems like you are doing a redundant serialize/deserialize. Glad you got it working though.

Comment: Sorry typo - `<%= venues[0].location.lat %>`.

Comment: @jens that's why I was unsure about why I needed to stringify it to work. I'm going to play around with it some more to try and remedy this.